# Does it exist a free version such as GoogleDocs or similar, but with LaTex syntax included in the editor?

Tags: collaboration, latex

I am looking for something similar to GoogleDocs or ShareLaTex, but so far the former does not provide LaTex syntax and the later has a licensing model I believe. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably better for http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This might seem to be a bit off-the-topic on the first glance. But given that the collaboration with remote authors working on Latex documents is very common in academia, I believe it is a good question.

Comment: What is the free version of ShareLaTex missing, that you require? There are several online LaTeX editors that have free plans, knowing what your exact requirements are will help us give you the appropriate answer.

Comment: Not sure if I got your question right. If I have, the answer would be https://www.authorea.com. Free for open access articles + 1 private one, paid otherwise. There is also https://www.writelatex.com.

Comment: Or the free version of [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/plans)?

Comment: sharelatex is opensource and you can run your own instance

Comment: ShareLatex only allows one collaborator for free in the subscription model as far as I can see, being that a major limitation. One of the main points was the former (collaboration and for free), and in addition the LaTex syntax. I can see the writelatex.com has the LaTex auto-complete, but not in the free version though. Probably I will try to install share latex, apparently it is open source now, but of course this will take more work to set up. Apart from that, I do not know if it provides auto-complete as I have not tried yet, thank you. http://tinyurl.com/oc9rjyg